# Can't find/install libXtst.so.6?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, netbeans, command-line

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm trying to install Netbeans 7.1(or later)
I have the .sh file, but it won't install, the error appears here:

```
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.918]:      at org.netbeans.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:81)
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.918]:     An error occured while initializing the NetBeans IDE installer UI.
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.918]:     Most probably the running JVM is not compatible with the current platform.
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:     See FAQ at http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUnableToPrepareBundledJdk for more information.
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:     /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:     
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:     Exception:
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:       /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:     
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:     You can get more details about the issue in the installer log file:
[2013-06-27 19:11:28.919]:      /root/.nbi/log/20130627191128.log
```

I don't have the libXtst.so.6 file in any directory, and I can't seem to find it anywhere to download. Has anyone else run into this problem, or know a work around?

Comment: Where did /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25 come from?

Comment: It's the Oracle one. I had problems with open jre

Comment: I would strongly suggest just running `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6- jdk` and see if that Java version is good enough for your purposes.  That was built on your platform and should work well out of the box

Comment: I had that before, and it was having errors with Netbeans. Trust me, I would rather use openjdk/jre than the Oracle ones, but it just doesn't work for whatever reason with Netbeans.

Comment: Whenever you run into problems with a software package under Linux, check what platforms are supported. http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_70_Supported_Platforms - if "I need this to work" is i mportant then you should only use one of those.  Here Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

**EDIT:** As mentioned by [Stephen Niedzielski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970346/stephen-niedzielski) in his comment, the issue seems to come from the 32-bit being of the JRE, which is de facto, looking for the 32-bit version of `libXtst6`. To install the required version of the library:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

---

Type:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libxtst6
```

If this isn’t OK, type:

```sh
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate libXtst
```

it should return something like:

```sh
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6       # Mine is OK
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

If you do not have `libXtst.so.6` but do have `libXtst.so.6.X.X` create a symbolic link:

```sh
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ ln -s libXtst.so.6 libXtst.so.6.X.X
```

Comment: That did nothing, it installed something but I still get the same error.

Comment: what do you get with `$ locate libXtst` ? Nothing ?

Comment: Okay, this works, I have the package now. All I need to do now is find out where I need to put if for script to see it

Comment: Now, I'm getting '[2013-06-28 00:24:46.802]:     /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64'

Comment: Try the other one of the 32-bit/64-bit versions.

Comment: Thanks, I had already done that, but yes it works, turns out I had the 32-bit of JRE instead of the 64-bit.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386`

Comment: +1 @StephenNiedzielski. ( Step 1) download http://www.ultramixer.com/download.html  Step 2) sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386 Step 3) run ./UltraMixer4.sh . Workings )

Comment: The answer above still works with Ubuntu 16 + Quartus II v12 32-bit edition. `sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386`

Comment: I'd like to point out that this didn't work for me. Turned out I didn't even have the i386 architecture installed. So I had to first: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i368` then `sudo apt-get update`. Then I could install the 32-bit package.

Comment: If you are looking for the i386 version of the file, it is in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6`

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me in Luna elementary OS

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem comes from the 32/64 bit version of your JDK/JRE... Your shared lib is searched for a 32 bit version.

Your default JDK is a 32 bit version. Try to install a 64 bit one by default and relaunch your `.sh file.

Answer (score 2):

Had that issue on Ubuntu 14.04, In my case I had also **libXtst.so** missing:

```
Could not open library 'libXtst.so': libXtst.so: cannot open shared object 
file: No such file or directory
```

Make sure your symbolic link is pointing to proper file, 
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and list libXtst with:

```
 ll |grep libXtst                                                                                                                                                           
 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        16 Oct  7  2016 libXtst.so.6 -> libXtst.so.6.1.0
 -rw-r--r--   1 root root     22880 Aug 16  2013 libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

Then just create proper symbolic link using:

```
sudo ln -s libXtst.so.6 libXtst.so
```

List again:

```
ll | grep libXtst
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        12 Sep 20 10:23 libXtst -> libXtst.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        12 Sep 20 10:23 libXtst.so -> libXtst.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        16 Oct  7  2016 libXtst.so.6 -> libXtst.so.6.1.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     22880 Aug 16  2013 libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

all set!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with CentOS 8 and all of the packages above did not solve my problem. When I reviewed the two folders that store these files (for 64 bit /usr/lib64/ vs 32 bit /usr/lib/) I found that the 64-bit folder did not have libXt (but I was on a 64 bit OS). So I ran:

> yum install -y libXt.x86_64

And this resolved my problem. libXt.so.6 was now in that directory.