# Running JavaFX Application using framebuffer error Cubieboard A10

Tags: java, linux, arm, javafx-8

Since javafx support Raspberry PI. I want to run FX application in frame buffer. I am using Lubuntu LCD display image.

When I am try to run JavaFX application

```
java -Djavafx.platform=eglfb Hello.jar
```

I am getting the following error

I am using java8 embedded hardfloat.

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
eglCreateWindowSurface failed! eglGetError 12291
eglMakeCurrent failed - 12288
Failed to create EGLContextGraphics Device initialization failed for :  es2
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:300)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:214)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:653)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:98)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:214)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:653)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    ... 5 more
```

Please help me to find a way out.

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185156/javafx-on-linux-is-showing-a-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-es2-s ?

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into it. But I am not able to understand why GTK library I need to run JavaFX on frame buffer?

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of research, you should consider reinstalling OpenGL ES and maybe GTK too. There's a problem during initialization and Java can't render the application.

It could be a problem from Java version used at runtime which has to be Java 8. Let's check the default java version used by your system :

```
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm
```

If it's not the right version, you can change it with this command :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You also can check that java is accessible with this command :

```
java -version
```

You can have more informations with these options :

```
-Dprism.verbose=true -Dprism.debug=true -Djavafx.verbose=true -Djavafx.debug=true
```

Comment: But i want to use it without GTK, only with Framebuffer support. I have installed GLES mesa libs. But it always show `no suitable pipeline found`

Comment: It could be a Java version problem, I edited my answer.

Comment: But i am using java 1.8 and -version is correct, and executing like `/opt/software/jdk8/bin/java -version` same when executing javafx jar file.

Comment: You could get more informations using these options. I begin to run out of ideas ^^'