# Can not build runnable jar file in eclipse using JavaFX 13

Tags: java, javafx, jar, runnable-jar

I have a problem with JavaFX. If I create a .jar file, and I will try to run it through the cmd, I will get an error - Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw. I found there a solution in Intellij idea ide, but I am working with eclipse and I couldn´t find there something similiar like in intellij idea. I am working with **JavaFX 13**

Complete error from cmd -

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no 
suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: just guessing, the `d3d, sw` aren't included/bound with your project in eclipse? (blind  shot)

Comment: What command are you running, exactly?

Comment: I am running this command:  **java -jar path.jar**
I can not run the .jar file what I have created, so I am trying to get a reason why

Comment: On which platform and how exactly did you build the jar file. Did you follow the instructions here? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ Remember that such a jar is in general not cross-platform due the native parts of OpenJFX!

Comment: did you use`runnable jar` or `jar`? have you installed efxclipse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX on Linux is showing a "Graphics Device initialization failed for : es2, sw"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185156/javafx-on-linux-is-showing-a-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-es2-s)