# CodenameOne css box-shadow

Tags: java, codenameone

Am trying to apply box-shadow to my codenameone components using css but adding something like `box-shadow: -1px 11px 18px 1px rgba(153,153,153,1);` generates below error message

```
CSS> Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
CSS> Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
CSS> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:263)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:157)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
CSS> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
CSS>    ... 1 more
CSS> Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:263)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:157)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
CSS>    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
CSS> Waiting for web browser
CSS> Waiting for web browser
CSS> Waiting for web browser
CSS> Waiting for web browser
CSS> Waiting for web browser
```

Comment: Are you using Linux? Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21203726/756809 The way this works we run the JavaFX web browser and grab a screenshot of the CSS border for complex border structures.