# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: on Linux but not Windows

Tags: java, linux

So I downloaded JNativeHook 1.1.4 from

[Link for JNativeHook](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/downloads/list)

And then I added it to my build path and compiled the program. I tested the program on my Linux VPS and get this error.

```
[root@nl ~]# java -jar file.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     
/tmp/libJNativeHook_468389387164048348.so: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The program was compiled using Java 1.6 and my VPS is running.

```
[root@nl ~]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.1.2.el6_5-x86_64 u65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

How can I get my program to work on Linux?. The program is working fine on Windows.

When i run **yum whatprovides '*/libXp.so.6** I get this.

```
libXp-1.0.0-15.1.el6.x86_64 : X.Org X11 libXp runtime library
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libXp.so.6
```

Comment: The Java library extracts some native code which in turn depends on an OS library that can't be found. You need to take steps to make _libXt.so.6_ visible to the process. [Here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6).

Comment: @McDowell I'm using a centos VPS, and those commands aren't working. How can I make libXt.so.6 visible on any Linux machine?

Comment: Try `yum whatprovides '*/libXp.so.6'`. With any luck you'll be able to use `yum install libXp.so.6`. There won't be a universal package management mechanism that works on every Linux distro.

Comment: @McDowell Updated the post with the result. I also installed it using    yum install libXp.so.6.

Comment: Install libXp with `yum install libXp.so.6`

Comment: I installed it. Would I have to do this on every Linux machine?

Comment: "Linux" is not a standardized system from a single vendor with a common way to provide libraries. You have some transitive X11 dependencies that may or may not be available on an arbitrary Linux system. Apart from "test + document for popular distributions" there are no simple answers.

Comment: For a complete list of dependencies and detailed complication instructions, please see the [wiki on github](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/How-to-build-JNativeHook-from-source#system-requirements-2).  If you're building form src, please consider building the trunk.  Version 1.1 has a lot of problems in it that have already been resolved.  Version 1.2 RC 1 is a little late, but binaries should be ready as soon as I finish up a few of the [outstanding issues](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/issues/list).