# Error: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, centos, ods

I am getting the error below when running a java file that tries to open an ods file.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/software/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeL

I tried - `'yum install libXext'` but got the msg - already installed.

Any suggestions?

Answer:

do yum install libXstst.so.6 
It installs and works fine

Comment: Similar problem was answered for Ubuntu  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6
Also, googling gives numerous results. Did you try any of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find/install libXtst.so.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17355863/608639)

Comment: For me only  sudo apt-get install libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386 worked fine

Answer (score 35):

In my case I needed to install additional libs.

```
yum install libXext.x86_64
yum install libXrender.x86_64
yum install libXtst.x86_64
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I was setting up an RHEL8 on AWS and had to install all 3 - sudo yum install libXext  /  sudo yum install libXrender  / sudo yum install libXtst.

Comment: what if I run it on serverless cloud, no access to the Linux os...

Comment: Works wonders for PyCharm installation on RHEL7

Comment: I also needed `sudo yum install libXft.x86_64`.

Answer (score 10):

First of all you can try to use the following command:

```
yum search libXext
```

Following this search you will find that you need to install the following library: libXext.i686 (or most probabily libXext.i386). After this you can run:

```
sudo yum install libXext.i686
```

As a side note, I needed also to install the following libraries in order to make my java application to work properly: libXrender.i686 and libXtst.i686. I think that this issue is due to the fact that we are trying to user a java 32bit version on a 64bit OS.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may installed 32 bit jdk in 64 bit system.if your CentOs is 64 bit, and you installed 32 bit jdk. You will get that error when you run jar

you can check CentOs is 32 bit or 64 bit,enter command:

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

If the CentOs is 64 bit, then you can remove the 32 bit jdk, and install a new one

Answer (score 0):

1. use file command to see if it is 32bit or 64 bit
   file /opt/software/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so
   its output should like:

   *ELF 32-bit LSB executable*
2. then install corresponding lib
   for 32 bit:

   sudo yum install libXext.i686

   for 64 bit:

   sudo yum install libXext

Answer (score 0):

For Arch I used pkgfile (which I installed with pacman) and then ran:

```
    pkgfile --update
    pkgfile libXtst.so.6
```

and it showed me extra/libxtst.

I installed with pacman and so far so good.