# Unidentidied Errors in mobaxterm

Tags: java

I try to compile my code on Mobaxterm and am getting all these strange errors. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
/usr/java/jre1.8.0_151/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)//
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at biuoop.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:36) //this is a library
        at AbstractArtDrawing.DrawRandomLines(AbstractArtDrawing.java:37)
        at AbstractArtDrawing.main(AbstractArtDrawing.java:15)
make: *** [run2] Error 1
```

If anyone has any idea what's going wrong, i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: are you sure this is related to mobaxterm? what do you mean compiled your code in mobaxterm?

Comment: I don't know if it's related. I used the program mobaxterm to upload my code and run it

Comment: upload the code to a server?

Comment: I would, but we need to specifically run it on this program before we submit it. if something goes wrong on the university server and we haven't run it on mobaxterm then we can't appeal a score.

Comment: you'll need to elaborate on "run it on mobaxterm" - mobaxterm is a terminal emulator so you are really running it (via the terminal emulated by mobaxterm) on some computer. this is either your own or another server if you've created a connection

Comment: it's my university's server

Comment: okay, do you have your code on github or somewhere?

Comment: particularly the document `AbstractArtDrawing.java`

Comment: There error is showing that you have a shared library missing. You might have to install libawt_xawt.

Answer (score 0):

According to this error message you need to install `libXext` for `i386` (the processor architecture)

[`libXext`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libxext-dev) is a package for [X11 window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)

you can check the below links for installation instructions:

ubuntu
[Can't find/install libXtst.so.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6)

centos
[CentOS: error: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741518/centos-error-libxext-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dir)

:)