# Who can help to resolve the issue when I install oracle client 12?

Tags: java, oracle

I want to install oracle client12 so I downloaded oracle db server from oracle site. I guess oracle client was included in it since I can not find separate package of oracle client(not instant version). But I encounter the below issues.

```
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2015-08-15_04-11-33AM. Please wait ...[ccms@igbdc80120 database]$ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/OraInstall2015-08-15_04-11-33AM/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1724)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
        at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1605)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1627)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(LookUtils.java:484)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(LookUtils.java:249)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:135)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1850)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:557)
        at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:792)
        at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:165)
        at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:182)
        at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:355)
        at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:130)
```

It can not find the .so file, but why it need to find the .so from /tmp? How to get around it? thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider using a Linux distribution supported by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The OUI comes bundled with its own copy of Java to minimize the required dependencies, this is the copy that's running from `/tmp`.  The unsatisfied dependency is `libXtst.so.6`.

Try this, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libxtst6
```

Comment: what does '/tmp/OraInstall2015-08-16_10-37-58PM/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6' mean? can not find libmawt.so or libXtst.so.6?

Comment: I believe `libmawt` is fine (it's part of the Java library which is part of the installer), but not finding `libXtst`, which is a depedency expected to be found on your system.