# Error in matplotlib import with Wakari

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to import matplotlib into an iPython notebook using Wakari, with the Anaconda environment np18py27-1.9. I am importing using:

```
 %matplotlib inline
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This yields the error:

```
 ImportError: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Because it is Wakari, I don't think I can update or reinstall the matplotlib package.  Importing pylab throws the same error. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

### Edit:

I was able to update matplotlib in my Wakari environment. I am now getting the following error:

```
  ImportError: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You may have to update `matplotlib` to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Well `.so` files are [shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809213/what-are-a-and-so-files) and (for what reasons I have no idea) you don't have them.

For your second error regarding `libXext.so` the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6) generally suggested are `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libxtst6`