# java exceptions while trying to install pycharm in ubuntu

Tags: java, pycharm

I am gettting the following errors while trying to install pycharm in my ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m;    support was removed in 8.0

Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:101)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
at java.awt.Cursor.<clinit>(Cursor.java:195)
at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.<clinit>(HTMLEditorKit.java:623)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:97)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:72)
... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:335)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:311)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:104)
```

i can't figure out why this is happening. Any help on this is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide your method of installation?
Are you using the bundled JRE provided in the Ubuntu package?
Apt-get/apt update libXext.so.6 see: [Can't find/install libXtst.so.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6)
For additional info see:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/requirements-for-pycharm.html